# How to do mysql query based on daily basis and at the same timing?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

How do I query on daily basis within a month and assigned time?

For example we have a column named "**timestamp**" and table "**xyz**" and we select date "2014-06-21 16:05" on the form

The query should take a month before which is within "2014-05-22 16:05" till "2014-06-21 16:05" same timing which is "16:05"

```
"2014-05-22 16:05"
"2014-05-23 16:05"
"2014-05-24 16:05"
"2014-05-25 16:05"
...
...
...
"2014-06-21 16:05"
```

Comment: You can set cron job in your server for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'not quite sure if this is you need:

```
SELECT 
    `timestamp`
FROM
    `xyz`
WHERE
    `timestamp` BETWEEN date_add('2014-06-21 16:05', INTERVAL - 1 MONTH) AND '2014-06-21 16:05'
    AND date_format(`timestamp`, '%H:%i') = '16:05'
;
```

Please let me if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: @EricT Glad I can help ^_^